# Prime spiral distribution into quadrants

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it known that the primes on the Ulam prime spiral distribute themselves equally
in sectors around the origin?  To be specific, say the quadrants?
(Each quadrant is closed on one axis and open on the other.)
For example, in the $50 \times 50$ spiral below, I count the number of primes in the four quadrants to be $(103,96,88,86)$ ($\sum=373$), leading to ratios $(0.276,0.257,0.236,0.231)$:

     [image: Prime Spiral]

For the $500 \times 500$ spiral, I count $(5520,5553,5535,5469)$ ($\sum=22077$) leading to
$(0.250,0.252,0.251,0.248)$.  Empirically there is a convergence to $\frac{1}{4}$, but I wonder if this has been proven?

Thanks!

Comment: I have played with those numbers using [Ulam's Spiral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/ulams-spiral-with-oppermans-diagonals-quarter-squares) with these quadrants. The distribution is fairly even. I don't know if anyone has proved anything about it. Here are some rough numbers for $1,712,012,977$ primes. $$\{427997847 \text{nq },428004936 \text{wq },427992540 \text{sq },428017654 \text{eq }\}$$ $$\{0.249996847424597529788 \text{nq },0.250000988164238663945 \text{ wq },0.249993747564916968500 \text{ sq },0.250008416846246837765 \text{ eq }\}$$

Comment: Now [crossposted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102075/).

Comment: And answered there by Terry Tao: Yes, a proof is available via known results that "the square roots $p^{1/2}$ of primes are uniformly distributed modulo 1."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so that this question can be marked as resolved:

An affirmative answer has been given on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102075/).